# How to dynamically format nested list of dict with less latency

Tags: python, list, dictionary, time-complexity, python-itertools

I need your expertise to easy the nested dictionary formatting. I have list of input signals which need to be grouped on the u_id and on timestamp field based on minute precision and convert to respective output format. I have posted the formatting i have tried. I need to easily format and process it as fast as possible, because time complexity is involved. help highly appreciated.

**Code snippet**

```
final_output = []

sorted_signals = sorted(signals, key=lambda x: (x['u_id'], str(x['start_ts'])[0:8]))

data = itertools.groupby(sorted_signals, key=lambda x: (x['u_id'], calendar.timegm(time.strptime(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(x['start_ts']).strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M'),'%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M'))))

def format_signals(v):
    result =[]
    for i in v:
        temp_dict = {}
        temp_dict.update({'timestamp_utc': i['start_ts']})
        for data in i['sign']:
            temp_dict.update({data['name'].split('.')[0]: data['val']})
        result.append(temp_dict)
    return result


for k, v in data:

    output_format = {'ui_id': k[0], 'minute_utc': datetime.fromtimestamp(int(k[1])), 'data': format_signals(v),
                'processing_timestamp_utc': datetime.strptime(datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")}
    final_output.append(output_format)

print(final_output)
```

**Input**

```
signals = [
       {'c_id': '1234', 'u_id': 288, 'f_id': 331,
        'sign': [{'name': 'speed', 'val': 9},
                    {'name': 'pwr', 'val': 1415}], 'start_ts': 1598440244,
        'crt_ts': 1598440349, 'map_crt_ts': 1598440351, 'ca_id': 'AT123', 'c_n': 'demo',
        'msg_cnt': 2, 'window': 'na', 'type': 'na'},
       {'c_id': '1234', 'u_id': 288, 'f_id': 331,
        'sign': [{'name': 'speed', 'val': 10},
                    {'name': 'pwr', 'val': 1416}], 'start_ts': 1598440243,
        'crt_ts': 1598440349, 'map_crt_ts': 1598440351, 'ca_id': 'AT123', 'c_n': 'demo',
        'msg_cnt': 2, 'window': 'na', 'type': 'na'},
       {'c_id': '1234', 'u_id': 287, 'f_id': 331,
        'sign': [{'name': 'speed', 'val': 10},
                    {'name': 'pwr', 'val': 1417}], 'start_ts': 1598440344,
        'crt_ts': 1598440349, 'map_crt_ts': 1598440351, 'ca_id': 'AT123', 'c_n': 'demo',
        'msg_cnt': 2, 'window': 'na', 'type': 'na'},
       {'c_id': '1234', 'u_id': 288, 'f_id': 331,
        'sign': [{'name': 'speed.', 'val': 8.2},
                    {'name': 'pwr', 'val': 925}], 'start_ts': 1598440345,
        'crt_ts': 1598440349, 'map_crt_ts': 1598440351, 'ca_id': 'AT172', 'c_n': 'demo',
        'msg_cnt': 2, 'window': 'na', 'type': 'na'}
       ]
```

**Current output**

```
   [{
    'ui_id': 287,
    'minute_utc': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 26, 16, 42),
    'data': [{
        'timestamp_utc': 1598440344,
        'speed': 10,
        'pwr': 1417
    }],
    'processing_timestamp_utc': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 29, 19, 35, 46)
}, {
    'ui_id': 288,
    'minute_utc': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 26, 16, 40),
    'data': [{
        'timestamp_utc': 1598440244,
        'speed': 9,
        'pwr': 1415
    }, {
        'timestamp_utc': 1598440243,
        'speed': 10,
        'pwr': 1416
    }],
    'processing_timestamp_utc': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 29, 19, 35, 46)
}, {
    'ui_id': 288,
    'minute_utc': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 26, 16, 42),
    'data': [{
        'timestamp_utc': 1598440345,
        'speed': 8.2,
        'pwr': 925
    }],
    'processing_timestamp_utc': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 29, 19, 35, 46)
}]
```

**Required Output**

```
    [{
    'ui_id': 287,
    'f_id': 311,
    'c_id': 1234,
    'minute_utc': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 26, 16, 42),
    'data': [{
        'timestamp_utc': 1598440344,
        'speed': 10,
        'pwr': 1417
    }],
    'processing_timestamp_utc': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 29, 19, 35, 46)
}, {
    'ui_id': 288,
     'f_id': 311,
    'c_id': 1234,
    'minute_utc': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 26, 16, 40),
    'data': [{
        'timestamp_utc': 1598440244,
        'speed': 9,
        'pwr': 1415
    }, {
        'timestamp_utc': 1598440243,
        'speed': 10,
        'pwr': 1416
    }],
    'processing_timestamp_utc': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 29, 19, 35, 46)
}, {
    'ui_id': 288,
     'f_id': 311,
    'c_id': 1234,
    'minute_utc': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 26, 16, 42),
    'data': [{
        'timestamp_utc': 1598440345,
        'speed': 8.2,
        'pwr': 925
    }],
    'processing_timestamp_utc': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 29, 19, 35, 46)
}]
```

Comment: It's not clear how you grouped items in your desired output. I see no items in input with same `u_id` and `start_ts`, but you somehow grouped two items with same `u_id` into one object and put third into another.

Comment: @OlvinRoght items should be grouped based on u_id and timestamp minute. if you see, 159844024, 1598440243 for u_id 288 belongs to same minute

Comment: have you profiled where the time is spent? I might try just writing a straightforward loop that goes thru the inputs and stores the signals based on the IDs - maybe the sorts are not necessary and take a lot of time.

Comment: @basic, `groupby(signals, lambda x: (x['u_id'], x['start_ts'] // 60 * 60))` will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, let's define simple function which will extract from each object keys which required for grouping:

```
def extract(obj):
    return obj['u_id'], obj['f_id'], obj['c_id'], obj['start_ts'] // 60 * 60
```

*Note: to implement "minutes precision" I've divided timestamp to 60 to cut seconds and multiply to 60 to get valid timestamp back.*

Then let's group objects and form final list:

```
from itertools import groupby
from datetime import datetime
...
final_output = []
for (uid, fid, cid, ts), ss in groupby(sorted(signals, key=extract), extract):
    obj = {
        'ui_id': uid,
        'f_id': fid,
        'c_id': int(cid),
        'minute_utc': datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts),
        'data': [],
        'processing_timestamp_utc': datetime.utcnow()
    }
    for s in ss:
        obj['data'].append({
            'timestamp_utc': s['start_ts'],
            **{i['name']: i['val'] for i in s['sign']}
        })
    final_output.append(obj)
```

To print `final_output` in readable form we could use `pprint`:

```
from pprint import pprint
...
pprint(final_output, sort_dicts=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you to write the code in a more straightforward way. If you can just go through the signals and organize them in one loop, maybe you don't need the sort and groupby which may be heavier.

As you want to gather the signals based on the u_id, a dictionary is handy to get a single entry per u_id. This does that much, you just need to add creating the output based on this organized dict of signals:

```
organized = {}
      
for s in signals:
  u_id = s['u_id']
  
  entry = organized.get(u_id, None)
  if entry is None:
    entry = []
    organized[u_id] = entry  
  entry.append(s)      

pprint.pprint(organized)
```

Is executable there, and output pasted below, https://repl.it/repls/ShallowQuintessentialInteger

```
{287: [{'c_id': '1234',
        'c_n': 'demo',
        'ca_id': 'AT123',
        'crt_ts': 1598440349,
        'f_id': 331,
        'map_crt_ts': 1598440351,
        'msg_cnt': 2,
        'sign': [{'name': 'speed', 'val': 10}, {'name': 'pwr', 'val': 1417}],
        'start_ts': 1598440344,
        'type': 'na',
        'u_id': 287,
        'window': 'na'}],
 288: [{'c_id': '1234',
        'c_n': 'demo',
        'ca_id': 'AT123',
        'crt_ts': 1598440349,
        'f_id': 331,
        'map_crt_ts': 1598440351,
        'msg_cnt': 2,
        'sign': [{'name': 'speed', 'val': 9}, {'name': 'pwr', 'val': 1415}],
        'start_ts': 1598440244,
        'type': 'na',
        'u_id': 288,
        'window': 'na'},
       {'c_id': '1234',
        'c_n': 'demo',
        'ca_id': 'AT123',
        'crt_ts': 1598440349,
        'f_id': 331,
        'map_crt_ts': 1598440351,
        'msg_cnt': 2,
        'sign': [{'name': 'speed', 'val': 10}, {'name': 'pwr', 'val': 1416}],
        'start_ts': 1598440243,
        'type': 'na',
        'u_id': 288,
        'window': 'na'},
       {'c_id': '1234',
        'c_n': 'demo',
        'ca_id': 'AT172',
        'crt_ts': 1598440349,
        'f_id': 331,
        'map_crt_ts': 1598440351,
        'msg_cnt': 2,
        'sign': [{'name': 'speed.', 'val': 8.2}, {'name': 'pwr', 'val': 925}],
        'start_ts': 1598440345,
        'type': 'na',
        'u_id': 288,
        'window': 'na'}]}
```

Comment: He wants signals to be grouped by `'u_id'`, `'f_id'`, `'c_id'` and timestamp from `'start_ts'` with minutes precision.

Comment: he said he only wants to group by u_id though. i didn't understand the logic for timestamps but maybe going in steps to first group by the u_ids and then handle the timestamps works, dunno